# Visual mode in vim not working

Tags: vim

This might sound like a trivial issue but it is bugging me for some time now. I have been using Vim on a Linux server since long and I used to access this Linux server using PuTTY in a Windows XP desktop computer.

Now I have moved to Windows 7 and still use PuTTY to access the same server. The problem is that visual mode has stopped working on the server. When I was on Windows XP, to enter C style comments `//`, I would do:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual mode
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> to select columns across lines
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to enter insert mode and add `//`
4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to copy text to columns in all lines

Now in Windows 7, the behavior of PuTTY/Vim has changed. When I now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, it enters visual mode (I see it in the status bar). But when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> to select columns across lines, Vim exits visual mode and goes to command mode.

I am not able to figure out if it is an issue with Vim or PuTTY or Windows. Since I have not modified any Vim settings on the server, I suspect it is some configuration with PuTTY but I am not able to figure out what. PuTTY version is 0.63.10044.0, Vim is 7.0.

Comment: Drop the Shift+Down habbit and use hjkl, Ctrl+F and Ctrl+B to select what you need.

Comment: Shift + Down doesn't work for me even in Debian. Ctrl+F works, so it seems more portable, so it seems the way to go.

Comment: what is shift-down supposed to do that down and pgdn don't?

Comment: You can simply use DownArrow instead of Shift-DownArrow. I suspect your previous terminal was just ignoring Shift, and your current terminal is doing something with it. Vim just wants a plain old DownArrow in that scenario.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking out [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) for commenting out blocks, although you still need a working visual selection for that.